# Reference an Image from a Scald ID

Tags: media, services, scald

I am using the Services (7.x-3.7) module to provide a REST API to our website content. However I have a problem with returning images. I am using Scald (7.x-1.1) to manage our media items. This means that when I attempt to GET a node (example.com/rest/node/25592) I get each field for the node in question nicely wrapped in JSON but for the image instead of an image path and file-name I get the Scald ID as follows:

```
field_event_image: {
und: [1]
0: {
sid: "15775"
}-
-
}
```

How can a client application reference the image path from the SID? I know I can use example.com/atom/15775 but this gives me back a themed node page containing the image - it contains the menu and default theme elements so it is not trivial or efficient to retrieve the image path from the source - though it could be done with some client side parsing. What I am looking for is a means to reference the image path directly using the SID. I am trying to keep the number of API calls to a minimum. Alternatively is there some way to configure the Services module to return the image path?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way – this is how to retrieve image url and image html from given `sid`:

```
if(isset($vars['node']->field_teaserbild['und'][0]['sid'])) {

    $img = $vars['node']->field_teaserbild['und'][0]['sid'];
    $atom = scald_atom_load($img);
    $image_uri = $atom->base_entity->uri;
    $vars['img_style_url'] = image_style_url('my_img_style', $image_uri); // style_url
    $vars['img_html'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'my_img_style', 'path' => $image_uri)); // html

}
```

Just in case somebody is still hoping for an answer…